Determine continuity of $[xy]\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ at (0,0)

Consider function
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      [xy]\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y) = (0,0) 
   \end{cases}$$
Determine the continuity of this function at the origin.Where [.] denotes greatest integer function.

I initially thought the function wouldn't be continuous because it was in some neighbourhood around the origin such that
$0\le|xy|<1$.
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{-xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, & xy<0 \\
      0, & xy \ge 0 ,
   \end{cases}$$
Taking a path $y=-x$ the function becomes,
$$f(x) = [-x^2]\frac{-x^2}{4x^4} = \frac{-[-x^2]}{4x^2}$$
Along this path when $x \in [-1,1]-\{0\}$ the function becomes
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4x^2}$$
And $\lim_{(x,y)  \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ along path $y = -x$ is equal to $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{4x^2}$ which does not exist.
$\therefore$ $\lim_{(x,y)  \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ along path $y = -x$ does not exist.
Thus the function is not continuous at (0,0).
However the answer key for this question said that the function would be continuous at the origin. I wanted to check if my reasoning was correct or if I'm missing something.

I think there is an error in your answer key. Your argument showing that the limit does not exist is entirely correct.

This function is constantly $0$ in a neighborhood of the origin, so it is continuous there. For $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{x,y\in (-1,1)}$, note that $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{0\leq |xy|<1}$ so $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\lfloor xy\rfloor = 0}$.
Perhaps you don't mean the greatest integer function (floor), but rather the least integer function (ceil)? "Greatest integer" means "greatest integer less than or equal to $x$", and "least integer" means "least integer greater than or equal to $x$".
EDIT: This answer is incorrect as OP points out.

If $xy$ is negative the floor is $-1$ not $0$.

I did mean the floor function or gif. And$ [0.25 \times -0.5] = -1$

Ah, yes, of course you are right, +1 for you.
